# Ajax is not responding when my cart contains only one item

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb, handlebars.js

In my shopping cart page I'm trying to delete a product when a user selects product quantity which is less than one. This change should be reflect on the products total too. I'm using ajax for this purpose and it deleting products only when the cart contains multiple items but not in the case of single item.

### 1.route

```
router.post('/change-product-quantity', (req, res, next) => {
  userHelpers.changeProductQuantity(req.body).then(async (response) => {
   response.total = commaNumber(await userHelpers.getTotalAmount(req.body.user))
   res.json(response)
  })
})
```

### 2.changeProductQuantity() function

```
changeProductQuantity: (details) => {
  details.count = parseInt(details.count)
  details.quantity = parseInt(details.quantity)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (details.count === -1 && details.quantity === 0) {
      db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).
      updateOne({
        _id: objectId(details.cart)
      }, 
      { $pull: { products: { item: objectId(details.product) } }
      }).then((response) => {
        resolve({ removeProduct: true })
      })
    } else {
      db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION)
        .updateOne({
            _id: objectId(details.cart),
            'products.item': objectId(details.product)
          },
          { $inc: { 'products.$.quantity': details.count }}
        ).then((response) => {
          resolve({ qtyChange: true })
        })
    }
  })
}
```

### 3.Ajax

```
function changeQuantity(cartId, proId, userId, count) {
  count = parseInt(count)
  let quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML)
  let qty = quantity + count
  console.log("Qty:" + qty)
  console.log("Count" + count)

  $.ajax({
    url: '/change-product-quantity',
    data: {
      cart: cartId,
      product: proId,
      user: userId,
      count: count,
      quantity: qty
    },
    method: 'post',
    success: (response) => {
      console.log(response)
      if (response.removeProduct) {
        setTimeout(function() { // wait for 5 secs(2)
          location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
        }, 5000);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML = quantity + count
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = response.total
      }
    }
  })
}
```

### 4.output Screens (both success cases and failure cases)

[image: Image1-success]

In this image as you can see user has multiple products in their cart. When user changes 2nd product quantity, the 'qtyChange' object become true whereas, he/she clicks on (-) button when the quantity reaches to zero 'removeProduct' becomes true. I have marked those changes right side of this image.

[image: Image2-error]

Here in this image you can see that I have tried to decrease quantity from 1 to zero. It should be deleted in such cases as I mentioned earlier. But it doesn't deleting. It  not displaying removeProduct object as you see in the previous image. When it happens I'm getting the below error in console.

[image: error in console]

It says total is undefined. Why it's happening ? Where did made the mistake ? Please help..

Comment: your code trow error here ```{ $pull: { products: { item: objectId(details.product) } }```. which give response undefined. and  response.total give total of undefinded. you need to use try catch or reject/resolve from promise in all condition.

Comment: could you please share how to do that ?

Comment: I'm new to nodejs so donno how to write these things in a correct manner. if you can provide a model i can write it my own.

Comment: You did great job. code write is art which come with practice and time. Even i need so much improvement. And I am terriable teacher.

Comment: The reason I can't able to delete a product when it's quantity is equals to 1 is because of the variable total getting undefined . Handling this error using a catch block would be resolve this issue. But I don't know  how to handle this . Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch and if response is not return from promise create own response and return data

```
router.post('/change-product-quantity', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let response = await userHelpers.changeProductQuantity(req.body)
    if(response) {
      response.total = commaNumber(
        await userHelpers.getTotalAmount(req.body.user)
      )
    } else {
      response = {}
      response.total = commaNumber(
        await userHelpers.getTotalAmount(req.body.user)
      )
    }
    res.json(response)
  } catch(error) {
    res.json({ total: 0 })
  }
})
```

Comment: do I need to include a reject in case in promise ?

Comment: no need with that. But it is good code of conduct and good practice.